# Delete duplicated row and append the rest row to another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables in a PostgreSQL database, let say `raw` and `total` table. What I want to do is to create a query that check data in each row of `raw` table whether it is already exist in `total` or not. If yes, delete that row. If no, insert that row to `total` table. E.g.

`raw`

```
product       brand       Date
--------------------------------------------
pencil          A        2019-06-16 10:00:00
pen             B        2019-06-16 10:00:00
eraser          C        2019-06-16 10:00:00
```

`total`

```
id         product       brand       Date
--------------------------------------------------------
 1           pencil         A        2019-06-16 10:00:00
 2            pen           B        2019-06-16 10:00:00
```

Base on this the first two rows in `raw` will be dropped. And the last row will be inserted into `total` 
Result:

`raw`  (This table will be used later on)

```
product       brand       Date
--------------------------------------------
eraser          C        2019-06-16 10:00:00
```

`total`

```
product       brand       Date
--------------------------------------------
pencil          A        2019-06-16 10:00:00
pen             B        2019-06-16 10:00:00
eraser          C        2019-06-16 10:00:00
```

What I can think of is to first deduplicate the row in `raw` with `DELETE` 
Something like this (Not sure about the correctness of this query but I just want to simplify my idea)

```
DELETE FROM raw r
USING total t
WHERE (r.product = t.product AND . . .) --check all of the columns in raw with columns in total
```

to make the `raw` table to have only a data that not exist in `total` then using another query to insert all of them to `total`. But are there a better way on doing this within a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
  DELETE FROM raw
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM total WHERE raw.product = total.product AND ...)
) 
INSERT INTO total(product, brand, date)
SELECT product, brand, date
FROM raw;
```